# C language - insert string parameter into sqlite database %s doesn't work

Tags: c, database, sqlite

So I'm working with sqlite and I created this database:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
     "NAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL," \
     "LAST              TEXT," \
     "PIN               INT," \
     "DL                INT,"\
     "SSN               INT,"\
     "EMAIL             TEXT,"\
     "BALANCE           REAL );";
```

I'm trying to insert a value in NAME but it keeps giving the the error "no such column: John

This is how I try to insert it: (assume everything is declared)

```
strcpy(text, "John");
sprintf (sql,"INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES (%s',%d);",text,number);
```

When I use this line of code instead:

```
sprintf (sql,"INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES ('john',%d);",number);
```

It worked and I was able to insert these two values.

why isn't the first one working??  Please someone help

Thank you

Comment: You should **really** consider using [prepared statments](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) as using sprintf to create a query string is **insecure** and prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a ' before %s. This would be the correct sentence

```
sprintf (sql,"INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES ('%s',%d);",text,number);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

As I would prefer you would use [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), I will replicate your code with prepared statement.

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES (?,?);", 41, &stmt, NULL);
if(stmt != NULL) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "John", SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, number);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Using `sprintf` to create your statement is **insecure** and **error prone** , you should learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the beginning `'` in your first code snippet. That means, it will give you something like:

```
INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES (John',42);
```

which is probably why it's treating the unquoted `John` as a column name rather than a string.

The statement *should* be:

```
sprintf (sql,"INSERT INTO ATM (NAME,PIN) VALUES ('%s',%d);",text,number);
```

---

Two other things. Unless you're *certain* about the provenance of your variables, blindly injecting them into SQL statements is a bad idea, and opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Secondly, C is mostly a free-format language, you don't need those `\` character at the ends of the lines in your first code block.